# solution for integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^3-a}J_0\left(k \, r\right) dk $ involving Bessel function (Hankel transform)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, integral-transforms

during my research I am facing for the first time integrals involving Bessel functions. In particular i need to evaluate the following integral:

$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^3-a}J_0\left(k \, r\right) dk $

with $a$ and $r$ being two real positive numbers. $J_0$ is Bessel function of the first kind and order zero.

I know this can be seen as an Hankel transform of the function $\frac{1}{k^3-a}$ however I was not able to find reference for this transformation. Maybe it is a known one.

Unfortunately Mathematica is not helping in finding the solution to the problem. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Maybe a way of solving this could be using a complex decomposition of the fraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may go through the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) and partial fraction decomposition:
$$\mathcal{L}\left(J_0(kr)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+s^2}},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{k+b}\right)=e^{-bs}\tag{1}$$
leads to:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{J_0(kr)}{k+b}\,dk = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-bs}}{\sqrt{r^2+s^2}}\,ds \tag{2}$$
where the RHS of $(2)$ is a multiple of the difference between a Bessel $Y_0$ and a Struve $H_0$ function.

Comment: What about if we had the Bessel function of the second order $J_{2}$ in the integral? Do you think it has a closed form?

Comment: @SSCNapoli: if you are ready to accept a combination of Struve and Bessel functions as a *closed* form, sure. The Laplace transform of $J_2$ is similar to the Laplace transform of $J_0$ and the same argument applies.

Comment: many thanks for the quick answer, you might be interested to this other question i have about integrals involving Bessel functions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125838/two-dimensional-fourier-and-inverse-transform-of-fraccos2-theta-r2

Comment: I apologise for bombarding you with comments, however I was also interested to the case when the function to integrate was $\frac{e^{-k z }k }{k^3-a}$ (with $z$ a positive real number). I guess the steps would be exactly the same, but then the final integral would look like $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-b s -z}}{\sqrt{r^2+s^2}} u(s-z) ds$ where $u(x)$ is the heaviside step function (ref:wikipedia). Am I correct? can this be expressed as Struve or Bessel functions?

Comment: Yes you are. For more details, you may post a separate question and I will be glad to provide them.

Comment: thanks a lot! just posted the question, you can find it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131785/solution-of-the-integral-int-0-infty-frace-k-z-kk3-aj-0-left

Comment: What happened to the analysis for the other part of the partial fraction expansion?